# Testing multiple page level design changes for perfomance and preference

Tags: usability-testing, user-preferences

I was asked to pick one page on a large site and mock-up improvements for testing. I tested the old page with task analysis, satisfaction survey, and a card sort.

I changed about 15 aspects of the page including font size, leading, iconography, added progressive disclosure, and moved some of the standard article info, such as author, date, content owner, etc..

For testing the new page, I'd like to test performance and preference. My idea is to do task analysis on the old page, then the new page, and then ask for preference. I'd also like to do some remote testing, but don't have the tools to let people compare the actual pages.

How can I conduct remote multivariate testing with Optimal Sort on a static image of a different design? Are there better general approaches?

Comment: "Any ideas for remote multivariate testing with Optimal Sort on a static image of a different design? Are there better general approaches?" Can you explain this line ,I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do

Comment: I hope you plan to use either images of both systems or prototypes of both systems. Image against prototype is just not a good idea. To a user a working prototype is very different from an image of a system. Pardon me if I have got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Googe Webite Optimizer multivariate experiments.
Here is how to test several pages http://elnostreraco.com/blog/test-multivariant-plantilla-google-website-optimizer/ (in catalan, use translator)  You may not test all at once. Check duration calculator and try user testing key tasks before.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The task analysis will be done on different versions of actual pages. Because of lack of time and testers, I'd also like to include some remote, unmoderated testing but I'm not sure what the best approach would be considering I have to test so many variables.

Comment: The idea of multivariate testing is to have multiple versions on real environment to track diferent behaviors on diferent versions.